# Method does not exist or incorrect signature : void

Tags: unit-testing, methods, apex, test-class

I'm getting the below error while saving the test class. Can anyone help on this please?

Error :

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void exceptionLogFromFlow(List<CS_ExceptionLoggerFlowTest.WrapperClass>) from the type CS_ExceptionLoggerFlow

Test Class:

@istest

Public class CS_ExceptionLoggerFlowTest {

```
@istest
static void SingleExceptionMethod() {
    WrapperClass wlu=new wrapperClass();
    wlu.apexClass ='CS_ExceptionLoggerFlow';
    Wlu.methodName='createExceptionLog';
    Wlu.exceptionMessage='message';
    Wlu.exceptionDated=System.today();
    Wlu.isAPIFailure = false;
    Wlu.userName='userName';
    list<WrapperClass> wpl= new list<WrapperClass>();
    wpl.add(wlu);
    Test.startTest();
    CS_ExceptionLoggerFlow.exceptionLogFromFlow(wpl);
    Test.stopTest();
}
public class WrapperClass {
    public String apexClass;
    public String methodName;
    public String exceptionMessage;
    public DateTime exceptionDated;
    public Boolean isAPIFailure;
    public String userName;
    
}
```

}

Main Class:

public class CS_ExceptionLoggerFlow {

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Exception Log From Flow')
public static void exceptionLogFromFlow(List<Params> inputVars) {
    String serializedstring=JSON.serialize(inputVars);
    String returnString = serializedstring.substring(1,serializedstring.length()-1);
    createExceptionLog(returnString);
}

@future
public static void createExceptionLog(String futureParams){
    List<ExceptionLogger__c> logList = new List<ExceptionLogger__c>();
    WrapperClass value = (WrapperClass) JSON.deserialize(futureParams, WrapperClass.class);
    List<WrapperClass> wpl= new List<WrapperClass>();
    wpl.add(value);
    
    for(WrapperClass vlu:wpl){
        ExceptionLogger__c log = new ExceptionLogger__c();
        log.Apex_Class__c = vlu.apexClass;
        log.Method_Name__c = vlu.methodName;
        log.Description__c = vlu.exceptionMessage;
        log.Exception_Dated__c = vlu.exceptionDated;
        log.API_Failure__c = vlu.isAPIFailure;
        log.User_Name__c = vlu.userName;
        logList.add(log);
    }
    insert logList;
        
}

public class Params {
    @InvocableVariable public String apexClass;
    @InvocableVariable public String methodName;
    @InvocableVariable public String exceptionMessage;
    @InvocableVariable public DateTime exceptionDated;
    @InvocableVariable public Boolean isAPIFailure;
    @InvocableVariable public String userName;
}

public class WrapperClass {
    public String apexClass;
    public String methodName;
    public String exceptionMessage;
    public DateTime exceptionDated;
    public Boolean isAPIFailure;
    public String userName;
    
}
```

}